# Pandas: Select rows containing only strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame that looks like this:

```
    [Column1]   [Column2]
0   16155.22300 1.246982
1   16193.009   BMS1P17,BMS1P18,BMS1P22,DUXAP8
2   16231.289   LINC01297
5   16265.05300 2.156268
6   16287.937   POTEH,POTEH-AS1
7   16288.53800 2.156268
10  17645.92500 44.765792
11  17646.335   HDHD5,HDHD5-AS1
12  17646.44400 44.765792
15  18073.59200 103.154877
16  18073.656   LOC101929372,SLC25A18
17  18073.84300 103.154877
```

I'd like to make list containing only strings from the column2. My solution to this is something like this:

```
my_list=list(i for i in ndf['LDU'] if isinstance(i, basestring))
```

For some reason it is not working and it returns all values. Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Column2'].loc[pd.to_numeric(df['Column2'], errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

Or if you want it in a list.

```
list(df['Column2'].loc[pd.to_numeric(df['Column2'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
```

Comment: Was about to post this; beat me to the punch.

Comment: It's "coerce"... I'll just leave this here: `df[pd.to_numeric(df['LDU'], errors='coerce').isna()]`

Comment: @coldspeed, `df[pd.to_numeric(df['LDU'], errors='coerce').isna()]`, would return the df where `LDU` is string. OP seems interested in a list of `LDU` that are string. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think "LDU" is their actual column name, and they've used [Column_x] here for clarity. I was just posting for OP's convenience.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
def checker(txt):
    try:
        float(txt)
        return False
    except:
        return True

df[df['[Column2]'].apply(checker)]
#    [Column1]                       [Column2]
#1   16193.009  BMS1P17,BMS1P18,BMS1P22,DUXAP8
#2   16231.289                       LINC01297
#6   16287.937                 POTEH,POTEH-AS1
#11  17646.335                 HDHD5,HDHD5-AS1
#16  18073.656           LOC101929372,SLC25A18
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[2,3,4], "b":["string",2,'m']})

my_list = []
for index, row in df["b"].iteritems(): #change b to your col name
    if type(row) == str:
        my_list.append(row)
print(my_list)
```

outputs: ['string', 'm']

Comment: Doesn't work (check your syntax), and not as quick as the other answers, not by a long shot.

Comment: Protip: If you want to answer questions quick, you need to get data quick. There's a function called `pd.read_clipboard` which lets you load dataFrames from clipboard. Good luck for the future!

Comment: Thank you, didnt know that. Also, there was . missing after df["b"]. Thanks for nothing that as well

Comment: No worries. Have an upvote from me, and keep contributing!